# How to decompile complex BAML to valid XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, baml

I tried ILSpy, but it failed:

```
System.NotImplementedException: StaticResourceStart
   в Ricciolo.StylesExplorer.MarkupReflection.XmlBamlReader.ProcessNext()
   в Ricciolo.StylesExplorer.MarkupReflection.XmlBamlReader.ReadInternal()
   в Ricciolo.StylesExplorer.MarkupReflection.XmlBamlReader.Read()
   в System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
   в System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
   в System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   в ILSpy.BamlDecompiler.BamlResourceEntryNode.LoadIntoDocument(IAssemblyResolver resolver, AssemblyDefinition asm, Stream stream)
   в ILSpy.BamlDecompiler.BamlResourceEntryNode.LoadBaml(AvalonEditTextOutput output)
   в ILSpy.BamlDecompiler.BamlResourceEntryNode.<>c__DisplayClass3.<View>b__1()
```

I tried Baml Viewer for .Net Reflector, but it was unable to generate valid XAML.

The main problem was with Binding that reference to wrong StaticResource.

For example (namedViews is CollectionViewSource):

```
   Visibility="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource namedViews}}"
   ToolTip="{StaticResource namedViews}"
```

What other applications exist to decompile BAML? Any patch to BAML Viewer?

Comment: I just used **ILSpy version 6.0.0.5559-preview2** to open a WPF assembly and it produced XAML from the baml without any problem.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this will help you, but if you can run the application, you can use [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) to run through the structure of a WPF application.

Other options:

- [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) (but I believe it needs the [Baml4dotPeek](https://github.com/cprieto/Baml4dotPeek) plugin which is based on Baml Viewer for Reflector, which, as you said, didn't work.)
- [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiling.aspx) (you have to register with Telerik, I believe)
- [Woodstock for WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WoodstockForWPF.aspx)

I've only tried Snoop and like it very much, but that didn't seem to solve your problem.

Comment: I can view ToolBarTrayControl, but Ribbon is not presented in Snoop.

Comment: Hm, no mention of ToolBarTrayControl or Ribbon in your question. I think you should elaborate a little more. Are you trying to find the bindings with wrong StaticResources? You could also try dotPeek (from JetBrains)

Comment: dotPeek plugin based on BAML Viewer for Reflector, and yes problems are same.
JustDecompile doesn't support BAML feature [yet](http://justdecompile.uservoice.com/forums/113277-justdecompile-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1893781-styles-explorer-baml-decompiler-and-codeviewer-f).
Woodstock ask for Full Trust.

Comment: Sorry, I'm all out of ideas :(